# Conexão FTP não está listando arquivos

Tags: java, ftp

Não estou conseguindo listar os arquivos da pasta via FTP (pelo Filezilla eu consigo acessar listar correctamente):

```java
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

ftp.connect("ip_ftp");
ftp.login("usuario", "senha");
System.out.println("conectado: " + ftp.isConnected()); //verifica se conectou
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("diretorio"); //informa o diretorio que eu quero acessar

System.out.println("Status: " +ftp.getStatus()); //verifica se ainda esta conectado
System.out.println(ftp.printWorkingDirectory()); //informa o diretório que estou

String[] arq = ftp.listNames(); //lista o arquivos
System.out.println("Listando arquivos: \n");
for (String f : arq) { //imprimre os arquivos
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

Porém esta dando o seguinte erro:

```
Permission denied: recv failed
```

Estou usando as seguintes bibliotecas:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
```

Answer (score 1):

Provável que seja algum bloqueio na porta 20, o FTP utiliza a porta 21 para autenticar e a porta 20 para trafegar dados.

Seu código **está trabalhando no** **modo ativo**, normalmente os FTPs em modo ativo ocorre problema de conexão na hora de listar e baixar arquivos, principalmente quando estão atrás de provedores ou Firewalls.

Se você utilizar o FTP **passivo** (que é o mesmo do Filezilla utiliza por padrão) provavelmente irá funcionar.

Um link mais detalhado sobre o como o FTP trabalha http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a pergunta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6990663/1518921) este problema:

> Permission denied: recv failed

ocorre devido a falta de um update (talvez nas versões mais recentes do windows não ocorra) que ocasiona problemas em conexões FTP em **modo passivo** no IPV4, segue o link:

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2754804/ftp-client-does-not-establish-a-passive-mode-ftp-connection-to-an-ipv4

Download do hotfix:

> https://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/kbhotfix.aspx?kbnum=2754804&kbln=en-US

Alternativamente pode tentar ao invés de usar o **passive mode**:

```
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

Trocar pelo **active mode**:

```
ftp.enterLocalActiveMode();
```